# r - Create possible outcome genotypes of offspring

Tags: r, genetics, population

Let there be two binary vectors `p1` and `p2` of length 20 that represent the genotypes of two parental individuals.

```
p1 <- sample(c(0,1), 20, replace=T)
p2 <- sample(c(0,1), 20, replace=T)
```

Then the first 10 numbers represent the alleles on one chromosome and the 2nd 10 numbers represent the alleles on the second chromosome, i.e. we are looking at 10 biallelic loci. Now I'd like to generate all possible genotypes that offspring individuals from both parents can have. How can I create these sequences under the assumption of recombination (i.e. if one allele at locus i is chosen from the 2 alleles of `p2`, the 2nd allele at the position i+10 has to be taken from `p1` and vice versa)?

Comment: It sounds as though your data structure is making things harder.  Wouldn't it be easier if each parent was represented as a matrix or dataframe with 10 rows (representing the 10 loci) and 2 columns (representing the two alleles at each locus)?  Then recombination would correspond to choosing one column from each parent.

Comment: Thanks for the question, @user2554330. Yes, it's an alternative way to view it. Nevertheless, I still have no clue how I can efficiently generate the possible offspring genotypes. Any idea?

Comment: There are 2^10 possible choices of alleles from each parent.  You could code those by writing the numbers 0 to 1023 in binary.  Then you just have one loop from 0 to 1023 for one parent, and nested within it another loop from 0 to 1023.  Decode the choices to construct the offspring genotype.

Comment: Hmm, I think there are 2^20 possible choices (2 alleles for every locus). And the solution sounds to be very slow ;) But maybe there's no better opportunity ... Thanks

Comment: 2^10 for each parent, 2^20 overall.  That's just a million, not infeasible.

Comment: My edit to the answer makes it about a thousand times faster.

Answer (score 1):

(NB:  I had the indexing in the offspring calculation wrong in an earlier draft.)

Here's a solution based on my comments above.

```
library(compositions)

p1 <- matrix(sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE), ncol = 2)
p2 <- matrix(sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE), ncol = 2)

for (choice1 in 0:1023) {
  p1choices <- bit(choice1, 0:9) + 1
  for (choice2 in 0:1023) {
    p2choices <- bit(choice2, 0:9) + 1
    offspring <- cbind(p1[cbind(1:10, p1choices)], p2[cbind(1:10, p2choices)])
    # record this somehow
  }
}
```

I left out the step of recording all the offspring genotypes.  You can convert the columns of `offspring` to two numbers in 0:1023 using

```
apply(offspring, 2, function(x) sum(x*2^(0:9)))
```

but it's up to you to figure out what to do with those.

Edited to add:

The loops above generate about a  million offspring, but in many cases, that's not needed.  If `p1` or `p2` is homozygous (equal values in both columns),
it doesn't matter which one you choose.  With the simple model used, on average about half the loci would be homozygous in each parent, so really only about a thousand choices are needed.  This version of the code takes that into account.  It's more complicated (and therefore more likely to contain bugs!), but about a thousand times faster:

```
library(compositions)

p1 <- matrix(sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE), ncol = 2)
hetero1 <- p1[,1] != p1[,2]
count1 <- sum(hetero1)
p1choices <- rep(1, 10)
p2 <- matrix(sample(0:1, 20, replace = TRUE), ncol = 2)
hetero2 <- p2[,1] != p2[,2]
count2 <- sum(hetero2)
p2choices <- rep(1, 10)

for (choice1 in 0:(2^count1 - 1)) {
  p1choices[hetero1] <- bit(choice1, 0:(count1 - 1)) + 1
  for (choice2 in 0:(2^count2 - 1)) {
    p2choices[hetero2] <- bit(choice2, 0:(count2 - 1)) + 1
    offspring <- cbind(p1[cbind(1:10, p1choices)], p2[cbind(1:10, p2choices)]) 
    # record this somehow
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks a lot!